# What are the linearised equations for the flexible economy in Smets and Wouters (2007)?

Tags: macroeconomics, new-keynesian-economics, dsge

To solve the Smets and Wouters (2007) model, we need the linearised equation for the economy when wages and prices are flexible (monetary policy rule depends on the potential output).

However, in their scientific article they do not provide those equations.

What are they?